# Каким образом буква "л" получила своё наименование?

Tags: история, историческая-грамматика, алфавит, буквы

Как получилось, что буква "л" (эль) стала единственной согласной, парной по твёрдости-мягкости, представленной в русском алфавите в "мягком" варианте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Эль"восходит к названию буквы l в латинском алфавите, где для него было фонетическое оправдание, поскольку этот звук в латинском языке был только полумягким. В русском же языке есть соответственно и мягкий согласный звук /л'/, и твердый согласный звук /л/. Поэтому некоторые языковеды считают, что, так же как и другие буквы (м, н и т.д.), служащие для обозначения и твердых и мягких согласных звуков (ср.: мох и мех, нос и нёс и т.д.), букву л (ср.: лось и лес) можно было бы называть не "эль", а "эл", тем более что любая другая буква, стоящая перед другой согласной буквой и обозначающая согласный звук, без дополнительных знаков обозначения мягкости чаще обозначает именно твердый звук, ср.: конфета (с твердым согласным /н/) и пенсия (со звуком /н'/). Случаев типа пенсия, когда согласная буква обозначает мягкий согласный (без дополнительных знаков, сигнализирующих о мягкости согласного звука), значительно меньше. Впрочем, это последнее положение на букву л не распространяется: буква л без знака мягкости звука /л'/ не обозначает (кроме случаев с удвоением букв: иллюзия, гулливый).

В школьной традиции буква л устойчиво называется "эль", однако, например, в Словаре современного русского литературного языка (в 17 т.) для нее указываются два наименования: "эл" и "эль".

При практическом использовании названия этой буквы чтение (произношение) ее колеблется: при чтении аббревиатур, образованных по названиям букв, типа ДЛТ (Дом ленинградской торговли), ВЛКСМ, ЛГУ (Ленинградский государственный университет) и т.п., чаще произносят название этой буквы с твердым согласным: "дэ-эл-тэ", "вэ-эл-ка-эс-эм", "эл-гэ-у" и т.п.

Уже и в учебниках для школы в таблицах названий букв имеется название "эл". Например, в учебнике Бабайцевой В.В., Чесноковой Л.Д. "Русский язык. IV - VIII классы: Пробный учебник" (М., 1988).

Comment: http://bibl.tikva.ru/base/B952/B952Part4-11.php